# Am getting compilation error whenever I execute

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_INSERT_OVERSEAS_COMPANY
( 
  COMPANY_CODE    IN   NUMBER,
  COMPANY_NAME    IN    VARCHAR2,
  STREET_ADDR     IN   VARCHAR2,
  COMPANY_STATE   IN   VARCHAR2,
  ZIP_CODE        IN   VARCHAR2,
  COUNTRY         IN   VARCHAR2,
  CONTACT_PERSON  IN   VARCHAR2,
  CONTACT_NUMBER  IN   VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN

     IF sysdate between trunc(sysdate,'DD')+interval '9' hour and trunc(sysdate,'DD')+interval '17' hour
     THEN 
         INSERT INTO Overseas_Company
         VALUES
              (COMPANY_NAME,COMPANY_NAME,STREET_ADDR,COMPANY_STATE,ZIP_CODE,COUNTRY,CONTACT_PERSON,CONTACT_NUMBER);
          ELSE  
               dbms_output.put_line ('Process is outside of normally working hours');    
        END IF;

END SP_INSERT_OVERSEAS_COMPANY;
/
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: and the error you get.... ?

Comment: The error is the slected program is in an invalid state for running. Recompile the program and try again.

Comment: From that error and the comments on jonearles' answer, this looks like SQL Developer, but it should report the column position too (i.e. `Error(24,30): PLS-00103 ...`). You'd only get that if you didn't have the semicolon at the end of line 24 (`END SP_INSERT_OVERSEAS_COMPANY`); or you were selecting the block of text to execute and missing the semicolon off. So something doesn't add up, and I think that might be a red herring. Can you `describe overseas_company` and add that to the question?

Comment: i soloved it thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should `COMPANY_NAME,COMPANY_NAME,...` be `COMPANY_CODE,COMPANY_NAME,...`?  The parameter `COMPANY_CODE` is not used in the procedure.  Are you getting numeric conversion errors?

Comment: The error is the slected program is in an invalid state for running. Recompile the program and try again.

Comment: wheni compile:Error(24): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ; The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

Comment: What program are you using?  The syntax looks valid for SQL*Plus.  Perhaps some other programs have problems with the `/` at the end.